# Which formula sums all values from a column in a line that contains a specific word?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Let's use this random spreadsheet to illustrate my problem.

[image]

What I want to do is a sum of all **Page Views (F)** that contains the **Category (B)** named /Online Computers. Which formula can I use to do that?

I wanted to Google it before asking here but I'm not sure how this is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `=SUMIF` as MaryC says, or the `=FILTER` function that I usually prefer:

```
  =SUM(FILTER(F2:F, B2:B = "/Online Computers"))
```

The `=FILTER` function filters your data so that only rows matching `B2:B = "/Online Computers"` are included.

See [the example spreadsheet I've set up](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_JOExvRCzkNwkqG8uFzEgTt7SaK-zMiBFmY_elSBrEI/edit?usp=sharing), and the [Google spreadsheets function list](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?rd=2).

Comment: Thank you, it also works! It's a semicolon instead of a comma though.

Comment: The `,` vs `;` depends on your locale settings.

Comment: Oh. What else changes from place to place?

Comment: Nothing else, that I am aware of.

Answer (score 1):

This is the function you want:

> SUMIF(range, criterion, [sum_range])
>
> Example SUMIF(A1:A10, ">20", B1:B10)
>
> Summary Returns a conditional sum across a range.
>
> range The range which is tested against 'criterion'.
>
> criterion The pattern or test to apply to 'range'.
>
> sum_range - [optional] The range to be added up, if different from
>   'range'.

More information here:   https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093583?hl=en-GB